# Core Data NSPredicate by relationship (fault)

Tags: objective-c, core-data, nspredicate, nsfetchedresultscontroller

Core Data. Say I have an entity called "Category" and an entity called "Item". Category has one-to-many relation called "items" pointing to "Item" and "Item" has to-one relation called "category" pointing to "Category" entity.
In a controller, I get selected Category and fetch all Items (I'm working with NSFetchedResultsController) using `[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"category == %@", selectedCategory];` where selectedCategory is that selected category `NSManagedObject`. In most cases it works fine, but I have noticed that sometimes this returns nothing. When that happens, this `selectedCategory` is showing relationship fault for it's property `items`. I have overcome this error by creating `[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"categoryId == %@", selectedCategory.identifier];` because I have id's stored.

I am interested in a right way of doing this and making sure that these faults never happen? Is that possible?

Cheers

Comment: I use  `category =` instead of `==`, and it works all the time. I don't know if that makes any difference but... just a suggestion!

Comment: I'll try that. I'm sure that this fault has something to do with my background refreshing and writing/deleting objects from CoreData, but I'd like to know a best way to achieve this.

Comment: If you just want to prevent the fault you can use `setRelationshipKeyPathsForPrefetching` [doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdPerformance.html). But I don't know why your predicate sometimes returns nothing...